# How to retrieve only particular part of string in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, string, t-sql, sql-server-2012

My data looks like that:

```
PrimISOcodeGL
99507 - Swimming Pools – installation & service – below ground - 1799 - Hazard 3
18501 - Supermarkets - 5411 - Hazard 1
91580 - Contractors Executive Supervisors  - 1541 - Hazard 2
10073 - Automobile Sales, Repair or Service Shop - 7539 - Hazard 2
```

How can I retrieve only the name between first and second "-"?

So it should be like that:

```
PrimISOcodeGL
Swimming Pools
Supermarkets
Contractors Executive Supervisors
Automobile Sales, Repair or Service Shop
```

I am trying to use function like `CHARINDEX`, `LTRIM`, `RTRIM`, `LEN`

Comment: Find first charindex. Take string from there + 1 till charindex of next hyphen. So, that will be substring with numbers passed in as charindex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a way using charindex and substring.

[ONLINE DEMO](http://rextester.com/RZOI27085)

```
declare @table table (PrimISOcodeGL varchar(256))

insert into @table 
values
('99507 - Swimming Pools - installation & service - below ground - 1799 - Hazard 3'),
('18501 - Supermarkets - 5411 - Hazard 1'),
('91580 - Contractors Executive Supervisors  - 1541 - Hazard 2'),
('10073 - Automobile Sales, Repair or Service Shop - 7539 - Hazard 2')

select
    ltrim(substring(substring(PrimISOcodeGL,charindex('-',PrimISOcodeGL) + 1,9999),1,charindex('-',substring(PrimISOcodeGL,charindex('-',PrimISOcodeGL) + 1,9999)) - 1))
from
    @table
```

Comment: Thanks for such fast respond. But this one doesnt stop after second '-'.
As a result I need just  `Swimming Pools`

Comment: Why use 9999 here?

Comment: Yes it does @Oleg see the online demo

Comment: Oh, sorry. It does stop. Sorry

Comment: @Amit arbritray value large enough to encompass the rest of the string regardless of how big it is (relatively). Basically a lazy and cheap way instead of using Len()

Comment: No problem at all @Oleg

Comment: Awesome, never see this way before. Thank you very much!!